# Canadian Payment Pro Sandbox Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Since the new developer site has been put online, it is no more possible to create payment Pro Account on the sandbox, since Canadian users can't either use the REST options, what can we do to test our Pro solutions ? When importing my test accounts, pro are automatically switched to basic business, and cleared my credentials infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently working towards resolving the issue.  As of right now, it is a hit or miss depending on the box that you hit.  You might try creating a US PRO account a couple of different times.  You may hit one of the boxes that are not currently experiencing the issues with account creation.  If you do hit one of the working boxes, you should get a pro account created with API credentials.

Comment: Since real clients are in Canada, won't we have problems ? Thank you, I'll be trying to create US Pro accounts

Comment: The code/API call would be the same.  The account features inside the account would be the only thing that you would see a difference with.  Some card types may not be supported, the layout of the profile taxes/shipping may be different.  However the taxes and shipping would not matter in the case of using pro since you pass those over in the API call.